# Learning differential/Riemannian geometry for PDEs

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

I know there have been threads on which books to learn DG/RG from but hopefully this is sufficiently different to avoid closure.

Can anyone recommend a book to learn DG/RG (whichever is appropriate) so that I can do PDEs on manifolds? At the moment I am reading through John M Lee's **Introduction to Smooth Manifolds** and I am wondering whether I really need to learn all the topics in it since it doesn't touch RG which I believe is more used in the theory of PDEs. Maybe there is a better text.

Also, any topics to particularly study or avoid would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: Michael Taylor's three volumes of _Partial Differential Equations_ does some PDEs on manifolds, and Jürgen Jost's _Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis_ may also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Thierry Aubin, [A Course in Differential Geometry](http://books.google.com/books?id=q2iS-aSeHK0C).*
An excerpt from its preface:

> The aim of this book is to facilitate the teaching of differential
>   geometry. This material is useful in other fields of mathematics, such
>   as partial differential equations, to name one. We feel that workers
>   in PDE would be more comfortable with the covariant derivative if they
>   had studied it in a course such as the present one.

---

At a more advanced level there is also:

*Thierry Aubin, [Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds: Monge-Ampère Equations](http://books.google.com/books?id=NcLiTzEwFbcC)*

Comment: @t.b. Thanks Theo

Comment: +1. A good book by a late master,although terse and challenging. If you like that kind of presentation a la Warner or Walshap, then this is one of the best.

Answer (score 3):

If you're assuming the Riemannian manifold has a fixed metric, then the most introductory source I've found is Folland, *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*, which discusses aspects of PDEs on hypersurfaces and the Laplace-Beltrami operator, for example.

If you're looking for something more advanced, but which avoids getting into curvatures,
then Grigor'yan's *Heat kernel and analysis on Manifolds* (AMS,2009) is excellent IMHO.